# Wrap and unwrap divs responsively

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of 6 DIVs which I want to wrap in a new div every X divs depending on the screenwidth of the browser.

So to start I have

```
<div class="blogItem"></div>
<div class="blogItem"></div>
<div class="blogItem"></div>
<div class="blogItem"></div>
<div class="blogItem"></div>
<div class="blogItem"></div>
```

So at 980px an above I want to add a new DIV with style="display: table-row;" to every 3 DIVs - thus making:

```
<div style="display:table-row;">
<div class="blogItem"></div>
<div class="blogItem"></div>
<div class="blogItem"></div>
</div>
<div style="display:table-row;">
<div class="blogItem"></div>
<div class="blogItem"></div>
<div class="blogItem"></div>
</div>
```

Then at between 400px and 979px I want it to wrap every 2nd div so it becomes:

```
<div style="display:table-row;">
<div class="blogItem"></div>
<div class="blogItem"></div>
</div>
<div style="display:table-row;">
<div class="blogItem"></div>
<div class="blogItem"></div>
</div>
<div style="display:table-row;">
<div class="blogItem"></div>
<div class="blogItem"></div>
</div>
```

And then below 399px every 1 DIV, so it becomes:

```
<div style="display:table-row;">
<div class="blogItem"></div>
</div>
<div style="display:table-row;">
<div class="blogItem"></div>
</div>
<div style="display:table-row;">
<div class="blogItem"></div>
</div>
<div style="display:table-row;">
<div class="blogItem"></div>
</div>
<div style="display:table-row;">
<div class="blogItem"></div>
</div>
<div style="display:table-row;">
<div class="blogItem"></div>
</div>
```

How can I do this?

The solution I have worked which works well on page load but does not update when you change the browser size is:

For 980px and above

```
var divs = $(".blogItem");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=3) {
  divs.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div id='wrapper' style='display:table-row'></div>");
}
```

For 400 - 979

```
var divs = $(".blogItem");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=2) {
  divs.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll("<div id='wrapper' style='display:table-row'></div>");
}
```

For under 399

```
var divs = $(".blogItem");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=1) {
  divs.slice(i, i+1).wrapAll("<div id='wrapper' style='display:table-row'></div>");
}
```

Which all together is called as:

```
function blogPadders () {

// read window size
var windowSize = $(window).width();
// set div var for wrapping in rows
var divs = $(".blogItem");

if (windowSize >= 746) {
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=3) {
  divs.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div id='wrapper' style='display:table-row'></div>");
}

}

else if (windowSize >= 371 && windowSize <= 745) {
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=2) {
  divs.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll("<div id='wrapper' style='display:table-row'></div>");
}

}

else if (windowSize <= 370) {
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=1) {
  divs.slice(i, i+1).wrapAll("<div id='wrapper' style='display:table-row'></div>");
}

}

}

blogPadders();

$(document).ready(blogPadders);
$(window).load(blogPadders);
$(window).resize(blogPadders);
```

Comment: To me it seems an [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). why do you actually need to wrap those divs? what is the result you're trying to achieve? Are mediaqueries not enough for your purpose?

Comment: What about use bootstrap? Perhaps it can help you wraping divs for all devices. Any way you can change the DIV'S style with jquery using the window size (when changes). CSS could hellp you too to achieve this.

Comment: I want to add in these new <div style="table-row;"> divs to make the set of DIVs behave like a table row - so they all sit inline regardless of each ones height based on filled content - the example I described above in code is massively simplified :)

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hkhan/ (resize the output window) I did with mediaqueries only (css)

Comment: @  Fabrizio Calderan - a nice solution - gonna persist with jQuery for now - but if this fails will likely use this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use loop:

```
var $div= $('#your_id div'),
    length = $div.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i = i + 3) {
    $div.slice(i, i + 3).wrapAll('<div class="group" style="display:table-row" />')
}
```

Like this apply the different script for different resolutions.

Example:

```
if($(window).width <= 768){
var $div= $('#your_id div'),
        length = $div.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i = i + 2) {
        $div.slice(i, i + 2).wrapAll('<div class="group" style="display:table-row" />')
    }
}
```

But I suggest you go through the bootstrap to build your website responsive. http://getbootstrap.com/

**Update:** to unwrap when resize:

```
$(window).on('resize',function() {
  //to unwrap 
  $('.group').contents().unwrap();
  //now use other codes here to wrap
});
```

Comment: So I would have an if statement like this for all screen widths? just gave that theory a test and it went mad and wrapped with the <div style="display:table-row;"> loads of times... will try again with this new code idea...

Comment: Afraid this doesnt work - when you resize it creates nests of the new wrapped div...

Comment: oh! use on resize method and unwrap first.

Comment: C-link - just updated my original question with my approach which works on page load but not resize - any ideas how to unwrap?

Comment: using $('.group').unwrap(); seems to unwrap ALL divs in the code though??

Comment: oh! sorry, use $('.group').contents().unwrap();

Comment: Yep - that works - just figured that myself :) thanks - good solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the screen size with jquery and also there is a resize function for handling screen  size changes - e.g:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $(window).height();
    $(window).width();
});
```

You can write a function that gets all divs with jquery and then iterates through them adding your `display` style every `nth` time where `n` is determined by screensize at load or resize.

Comment: Thanks - yep, got the resize handling all sorted - i also have a system to wrap the divs on page load - but need a way to change where the wrapper divs are positioned in the DOM on resize...

Comment: Perhaps - inside the resize handler -  remove all the wrapper divs and then re-add according to your page load criteria?