# Replace all instances of html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, replaceall

I'm trying to remove all instances of `</div><div class="product-list_row">` and replace it with `<!-- removed -->`. But I'm having no luck getting this to work.

I've been trying all sorts of solutions, some I couldn't get at all working, and others would only do the first instance.

I also **can't use a regex solution**, since this is on my Shopify website, and their liquid code doesn't work with regex.

I've been using this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.product-list').html(function(index,html){
        return html.replace('</div><div class="product-list_row">', '<!-- so cool -->');
    });
})
```

```css
.product-list {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}
.product-list_row {
  display:table-row;
}
.product-list_item {
  display:inline-block;
  @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    display:table-cell;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-list">
  <div class="product-list_row">
    <div class="product-list_item">1</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">2</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-list_row">
    <div class="product-list_item">4</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">5</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-list_row">
    <div class="product-list_item">7</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">8</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">9</div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Should be this:

```css
.product-list {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}
.product-list_row {
  display:table-row;
}
.product-list_item {
  display:inline-block;
  @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    display:table-cell;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="product-list">              
  <div class="product-list_row">
    <div class="product-list_item">1</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">2</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">3</div>
    <!-- removed -->
    <div class="product-list_item">4</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">5</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">6</div>
    <!-- removed -->
    <div class="product-list_item">7</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">8</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">9</div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

that is because there are whitespaces between the `</div>` and `<div class="product-list_row">`

try this instead:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.product-list').html(function(index,html){
      return html.replace(/<\/div>\s+<div class="product-list_row">/g, '<!-- so cool -->');
    });

})
```

```css
.product-list_row{
  margin: 10px 0;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-list">              
  <div class="product-list_row">
    <div class="product-list_item">1</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">2</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-list_row">
    <div class="product-list_item">4</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">5</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-list_row">
    <div class="product-list_item">7</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">8</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">9</div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

as for the cause of replacing only the first occurrence, please read this helpful [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: This looks like a great solution, however Shopify's Liquid apparently doesn't work with regex.  Thanks for the solution though, as this will be a great reference for non liquid frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex is not nearly as reliable as using dom methods

Move the child elements to first row and remove whole containers once emptied

```js
var $rows = $('.product-list .product-list_row'),
  $rowsToEmpty = $rows.slice(1);

$rows.first().append($rowsToEmpty.children())
$rowsToEmpty.remove()
```

```css
.product-list_row {
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-list">
  <div class="product-list_row">
    <div class="product-list_item">1</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">2</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-list_row">
    <div class="product-list_item">4</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">5</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-list_row">
    <div class="product-list_item">7</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">8</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution, however in not replacing the elements with the comment "<!-- so cool -->", I loose my ability to do the reversal of that code to replace the comment with the original div elements when the other conditions are met. Is it possible to leave the comment in place of the divs that are removed?

Comment: Numerous ways to store state before you do this and be able to undo it

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how that is done. Do you have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use the builtin jquery methods `unwrap` (which removes the parent element) and `wrapInner` to add a parent element to the children. Then the javascript simply becomes

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.product-list_item').unwrap();
  // This line is to put one single product-list_row around the entire thing
  $(".product-list").wrapInner('<div class="product-list_row">');
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.product-list_item').unwrap();
  $(".product-list").wrapInner('<div class="product-list_row">');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-list">

  <div class="product-list_row">
    <div class="product-list_item">1</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">2</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-list_row">
    <div class="product-list_item">4</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">5</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-list_row">
    <div class="product-list_item">7</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">8</div>
    <div class="product-list_item">9</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution, however in not replacing the elements with the comment "<!-- so cool -->", I loose my ability to do the reversal of that code to replace the comment with the original div elements when the other conditions are met. Is it possible to leave the comment in place of the divs that are removed?

Answer (score 0):

Add `id="product"` for the `class="product-list"`. Then you can do:

```js
var newDiv = document.getElementById('product').innerHTML;
var unwanted = '</div><div class="product-list_row">';
var comment='<!-- so cool -->';
newDiv = newDiv.split(unwanted).join(comment);
document.getElementById('product').innerHTML = newDiv;
```

```html
<div class="product-list" id="product">
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use regex, as this is in a shopify website and their liquid framework doesn't work with regex.

Comment: Check this out, It will replace all unwanted elements.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var length = $('.product-list .product-list_row').size();
    $('.product-list .product-list_row').each(function(index, obj) {
        if (length - 1 != index) {
            $(this).after('<!-- so cool -->');
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Answer (score 0):

I had to reverse the way I thought about it. Instead of starting with hard coded element wrappers and trying to remove them and replace with another element (comments), instead I should have thought to add the wrapping divs every X elements.  This is what I ended up referring to to get what I needed - [Wrap and unwrap divs responsively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22985134/wrap-and-unwrap-divs-responsively). Thanks for the efforts though!